# Swagger JSON - How could I fix a response render error?

Tags: json, swagger, swaggerhub

I have been trying to fix an error where the Swagger would not render my JSON response - [here is an attached picture of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l00Qg.png)

The console does not show any errors so I am struggling to allocate from where the issue could be coming - [here is the console result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3RWh.png)

I would be extremely thankful if someone could suggest a way to fix that problem.

Here is my code:

```
  "paths": {
    "/unit/{jobs}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Services"
        ],
        "summary": "Jobs information",
        "description": "Returns JSON with content of jobs details.",
        "operationId": "unitJobs",
        "security": [
          {
            "Application": []
          },
          {
            "Profile": []
          },
          {
            "Authorization": []
          }
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "jobs",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "description": "Jobs"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success!",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Job"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "Application": {
        "name": "X-Application",
        "type": "apiKey",
        "in": "header"
      },
      "Profile": {
        "name": "X-Profile",
        "type": "apiKey",
        "in": "header"
      },
      "Authorization": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer"
      }
    },
    "schemas": {
      "Job": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 2584075,
            "description": "Unique identifier"
          },
          "currency_code": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "GBP",
            "description": "Currency code"
          },
          "payment_method": {
            "type": "array"
          },
          "app_time": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 1504620000,
            "description": "Appointment time for the job in UTC timestamp"
          },
          "flexible_from": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": null,
            "description": "Start of timeframe to execute the job in UTC timestamp"
          },
          "flexible_to": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": null,
            "description": "End of timeframe to execute the job in UTC timestamp"
          },
          "insufficient_travel_time_warning_time": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": "1504616400",
            "description": "Time up until Pro should leave previous job in order to get to this job in time in UTC timestamp"
          },
          "total_formatted": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "£97",
            "description": "Price of the service after discounts"
          },
          "base_total_formatted": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "£97",
            "description": "Price of the service before discounts"
          },
          "price_notes": {
            "type": "array",
            "example": [
              "Credit applied",
              "Compensation included"
            ],
            "description": "Description notes for the price of the services."
          },
          "require_summary": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 4,
            "description": "\n * `0` - No summary required \n * `1` - Should send summary at the end of the day \n * `2` - Should send summary now \n * `3` - Can’t proceed until summary sent \n * `4` - Summary sent"
          },
          "work_time": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 120,
            "description": "Job duration in minutes"
          },
          "valid_to": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": "1504620000",
            "description": "Time after which job is no more valid and has to be updated in UTC timestamp"
          },
          "attachments.origin_key": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "checklist",
            "description": "\n Identifies where the attachment is coming from: \n * `checklist` - from answering a question that requires attachment \n * `job` - from job screen \n * `configurator` - from booking process when filling a choice item of type attachment"
          },
          "services_price_modifiers": {
            "type": "array",
            "example": ""
          },
          "reference_number": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "20082602SYS",
            "description": "Unique identifying number for each job"
          },
          "purchase_order_number": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "12-13-14-15-16",
            "description": "Unique number assigned to a purchase order form"
          },
          "contacts": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Contact"
            }
          },
          "message_templates": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MessageTemplate"
            }
          },
          "decline_reason_groups": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DeclineReasonGroup"
            }
          },
          "icons": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Icon"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Contact": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 203,
            "description": "Unique identifier"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "02034042956",
            "description": "Contact number"
          },
          "type": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ContactType"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Customer Service",
            "description": "Name of the corresponding department"
          },
          "display_positions": {
            "type": "array",
            "example": [
              2,
              3,
              7
            ],
            "description": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "MessageTemplate": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 15,
            "description": "Unique identifier"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "In front of the property",
            "description": "Template message title"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Dear [CLIENT_NAME], I am in front of your property. Please let me in or call our office on 02034041930. Your Fantastic Professional",
            "description": "The containing text of the message"
          },
          "vars": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Var"
            },
          },
          "destination_option_title": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "to office",
            "description": "Optionally defines the destination of the title"
          }
        }
      },
      "DeclineReasonGroup": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Technical issues",
            "description": "Decline reason title"
          },
          "sort": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 100,
            "description": ""
          },
          "decline_reasons": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DeclineReason"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Icon": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Key:",
            "description": "The name of the icon"
          },
          "note": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Yes",
            "description": "Addiditonal information about the icon"
          }
        }
      },
      "Var": {
        "properties": {
          "variable": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "CLIENT_NAME",
            "description": "Different client details"
          },
          "type": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/VarType"
          },
          "field": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "clientName",
            "description": "Fields where the client's information is filled"
          }
        }
      },
      "DeclineReason": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 11,
            "description": "Unique identifier"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Car is broken",
            "description": "The name of a decline reason"
          },
          "requires_comment": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "example": true,
            "description": "Determines whether the comment section is required to be filled "
          },
          "success_message": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Please contact Stanimir Tomov on 07472761402 - he can find you another.",
            "description": "The message which pops up after the request made is successful"
          },
          "sort": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 100,
            "description": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "ContactType": {
        "type": "integer",
        "enum": [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
        ],
        "description": "* `1` - Customer Service \n * `2` - Sales \n * `3` - Finance \n * `4` - Other"
      },
      "VarType": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "auto",
          "manual"
        ],
        "description": "* `auto` - information being filled automatically \n * `manual` - information being filled manually "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the json file or at least the relevant part.

Comment: @SamiAkkawi thank you for willing to assist me! Shall I post the whole code (its 365 lines right now, not the biggest) as I am not rly sure in which part the issue could be allocated?

Comment: yes please, you can edit the original post to add the code.

Comment: @SamiAkkawi thank you for the answer again. I have pasted the code, could you please have a look at it whenever you got time? Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the responses them selves, rather it is the definition of the 'payment_method' in the Job schema:

You need to define the items in an array definition, try this:

```json
"payment_method": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

Comment: That fixed the issue for me - i left it as I was unware how to define it, thank you so much mate, you are a legend!